# Excel: Total Sum of each group in pivot table

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I'm having a problem on my excel report I want to add total on each group on my pivot table.
See the pic:

[image]

The highlighted row is the `Calculated Item`.

I want to show there the total of `operation` and `Revenue`, any idea how will I do this? Thank you!

Comment: As the image only shows a  partial section of the Pivot Table, it's hard to tell you exactly how to achieve it. Usually you'd just have to activate subtotals in the PT settings. Look for "display subtotals" in this link: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/design-the-layout-and-format-of-a-pivottable-a9600265-95bf-4900-868e-641133c05a80

Comment: @RicardoDiaz I know how to show/use the subtotals what I want to do on my report is to show the sum of `Operation` and `Revenue` in the highlighted row. That row is a `Calculated Item` in pivot, I want to know the formula to put in `Calculated Item` to calculate the sum of `Operation` and `Revenue`.